# How I change the text width in the "Frontmatter" part?

Tags: margins, front-matter, elsarticle

I am using Elsevier document class (`elsart`) but I changed the page margins and also text width, but the text in "frontmatter" part remained unchanged. How can I change the margin or text width in that part?

My code:

```
\documentclass{elsart}

%for changing the margins and text wiidth
\oddsidemargin = 0cm
\topmargin = 0cm
\textheight = 25cm
\textwidth = 16cm

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

  \title{}

  \begin{abstract}
  ....
  \end{abstract}

  \begin{keyword}
  ....
  \end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{}

\end{document}
```

I want to edit the Abstract, Key words and Title "frontmatter" part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the inner `\@frontmatterwidth` length:

```
\documentclass{elsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example

%for changing the margins and text wiidth
\oddsidemargin = 0cm
\topmargin = 0cm
\textheight = 25cm
\textwidth = 16cm

\makeatletter
\setlength\@frontmatterwidth{16cm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\lipsum[2]
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{test}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much dear Gonzalo Medina, your answer was so useful for my problem. I text width is changed by your code. I am glad that someone like you is there to answer questions about LaTeX.

regards,
Mohammad.